# Getting error for declaring swift protocol delegate variable in objective c

Tags: objective-c, swift, protocols

Error: Can not find protocol declaration for 'GameDelegate';

```swift
//Swift protocol
import AVFoundation
import UIKit;

@objc protocol GameDelegate {
    func lostConnection()
}
```

Objective C class:

```Objective-C
//play.h file
#import "SimpliSafe-Swift.h"

@interface SSStreamManager : NSObject 

@property (assign) id<GameDelegate> delegate

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don’t import the Swift generated header into a header file! Replace

```
#import "SimpliSafe-Swift.h"
```

With

```
@protocol GameDelegate;
```

Comment: … and put `#import "SimpliSafe-Swift.h"` in your `.m` file.

Comment: No doubt, but that's not the same question, is it? I answered _this_ question, the question you asked. You got a "Can not find protocol declaration" error; now that error has gone away. Done. If you have a new question, ask it as a new question.

Comment: Thanks @matt. It helped to go away above error. I may need to open new ticket for accessing protocol methods since I am getting error as "No known instance method for selector 'lostConnection'"